# VMware kernel module: a compatible version of gcc was not found

Tags: kernel, virtual-machine, gcc, vmware

When running the VMware kernel module updater, I get the following message:

`A compatible version of gcc was not found.`

How can I setup GCC to compile the VMware kernel module?

[image]

[image]

Comment: GCC is the compiler used to build the kernel module. It is possible it is not currently installed. Can you specify which distribution you are using?

Answer (score 7):

I hope this solves your problems.

> Upgrade Kali to the Latest Which is 4.8.0-kali1-amd64

```
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source

tar xf vmmon.tar

tar xf vmnet.tar

cd vmmon-only

make

cd ../vmnet-only

make

cd ..

mkdir /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc

cp vmmon.o /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc/vmmon.ko

cp vmnet.o /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc/vmnet.ko

depmod -a

/etc/init.d/vmware restart
```

Every time there's a new build for Kali, you have to go through these steps again.

Comment: i do it, but i got same problem !

Comment: What was the Error you got. After running this command

Comment: I think line 6 should be `cd ../vmnet-only`.  Also, this worked like a charm--thanks.

Comment: Worked for me on Mint 18.1 with kernel 4.9.20. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me on Kali rolling.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to install the basic development tools and libraries for this. Depending if you are using a Debian derivative (Ubuntu/Mint/Kali) or a Red Hat based system (RHEL/CentOS) the commands to install are different:

**Debian based**

```
apt-get install build-essential
```

**Red Hat based**

```
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

As a side note there is a package called open-vm-tools that provides the same functionality as VMware tools but are fully open source and better supported.

Comment: same problem , nothing change

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Kali Linux Rolling Edition, just browse and select `gcc-5` which is in `/usr/bin` or just type `/usr/bin/gcc-5` in the location field, and press "Install".

Answer (score 2):

I followed the answer by Ogheneneovie Ralph Otutu which used to work in previous kernels but does not seem to work on newer kernels. I was trying to compile the modules for `vmware 12.5.9` on kernel `4.15.0-kali3-amd64` when I got some errors:

```
/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c: In function ‘LinuxDriverInitTSCkHz’:
/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:268:22: error: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]                                 
    tscTimer.function = LinuxDriverEstimateTSCkHzDeferred;
                      ^
/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:270:12: error: ‘struct timer_list’ has no member named ‘data’
    tscTimer.data     = 0;
            ^
/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c: In function ‘init_module’:
/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:312:4: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘init_timers’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
    init_timer(&linuxState.pollTimer);
    ^~~~~~~~~~
...
```

Apparently changes in the Linux kernel made the VMware module sources incompatible.

To make this work I downloaded the patched source files for my version of VMware from https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/branches and followed the same steps as described by Ogheneneovie Ralph Otutu, i.e.:

```
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source

wget https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/archive/player-12.5.9.zip

unzip player-12.5.9.zip

cd vmware-host-modules-player-12.5.9/vmmon-only/

make

cd ../vmnet-only/

make

cd ..

mkdir /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc

cp vmmon.o /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc/vmmon.ko

cp vmnet.o /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc/vmnet.ko

depmod -a

/etc/init.d/vmware restart
```

Comment: it worked.  perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have gcc installed.

Just try this:

```
gcc --version
```

You will probably get that gcc command is not installed or something like that.

Solution? Simple!

```
apt-get update
apt-get install gcc
```

In case you are missing gcc, there is good change that make is also not installed.

```
apt-get install make
```

and then re-run instalation of vmware tools.

Comment: Even with GCC installed I still get this issue (Fedora 30). It seems like it wants a very specific version of GCC

Answer (score 0):

This is a super nasty hack, but here's what I did to get the version I needed of GCC (8.3.1 in this case). I am on Fedora 30 which has 9.x right now. I'm sure this is not the *right* way, but I didn't know of a better way to grab the right version of GCC.

1. Used Docker to start a new container for Fedora 29: `docker run --rm -it fedora:29 bash`
2. Installed the needed GCC tools within the container: `dnf install @development-tools`
3. Copied the GCC installation out to a folder on my machine: `docker cp {containerid}:/usr/ {some_folder_on_my_machine}`. You can look at the running containers with `docker ps -a` to find the container ID :) You may have to do this with `sudo`
4. If you had to use `sudo`, take ownership of the newly copied folder `sudo chown -R {user}:{user} {the_folder}`
5. Point VMware at the folder where you copied it out, for example `{the_folder}/bin/gcc`